# Although the frontend compiles correctly both using docker-compose up and ng serve works properly only with ng serve

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, docker

Although the frontend compiles correctly both using `docker-compose up` and `ng serve` works properly only with `ng serve`. When I open `localhost:4200` my website is not loading. After `ng serve` works correctly. I would like to run it with Docker. In both cases I get:

```
angular_1  | ** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200 **
angular_1  | Hash: 23dc61d32587641214e0                                                                
angular_1  | Time: 25229ms
angular_1  | chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 222 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 113 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 38 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 6.34 MB [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
angular_1  | webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Dockerfile in frontend directory:

```
# Create image based on the official Node 6 image from dockerhub
FROM node:6

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker-compose.yml in main directory:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  django:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  angular:
    build: frontend
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
      - django
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your command

```
ng serve
```

to

```
ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

in package.json

Comment: I have changed `"start": "ng serve"` to `"start": "ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check"` but there is still the same problem. Have I change my docker-compose.yml or Dockerfile, too?

Comment: Use `docker-compose up --build -d` to rebuild the image

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much. Can you explain what was the problem? During docker-compose I get `The option '--disable-host-check' is not registered with the serve command. Run ng serve --help for a list of supported options.
`

Comment: The problem was that ng server by defaults listen on `127.0.0.1` and that means only traffic inside the container can reach it. From outside when traffic comes it doesn't listen

Comment: Traffic means that if I don't use external APIs in my project then it will work with `ng serve`?

Comment: You can remove the `--disable-host-check` it is not needed anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153744/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-wahtdbogh).